# Auto start apps and workspace allocation

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop-environment, workspaces

How can I get Ubuntu 22.04.02 to maintain window position after a reboot for programs that are included in Startup Application list?

To give a general description of the problem, when I reboot my computers with Ubuntu 22.04.02, the specific monitor and workspace position for a window that was open before the reboot is not maintained.  Because I tend to have a lot of windows open at a time, I then have to manually move individual windows back to their previous workspace and monitor position after a reboot.  To clarify, I will provide an example.  An instance of Firefox that has a few photo editing web pages is open in workspace 3 out of 7 on monitor 2 out of 3 (I have three monitors).  Because Firefox is included in the Startup Applications list, this instance of Firefox is launched automatically after reboot.  Also, because Firefox sessions are retained and launched when Firefox is restarted, that same window I mentioned is launched upon reboot.  When I reboot the computer, the aforementioned instance of firefox is launched, but the position is not maintained. All instances of Firefox are opened on a single monitor, in the primary workspace.  I then have to manually move each instance of Firefox to the positions they had before the computer was rebooted.  I used Firefox as an example.  Every other program that is included in the Startup Application list misbehaves upon reboot in the same way.

Desktop environment is Gnome.

Ubuntu 20.04 places windows in their previous locations across monitors and workspaces after reboot correctly.  Ubuntu 22.04.02 does not.  I am asking how to force Ubuntu 20.04.02 to remember exactly where each instance of programs listed int he Startup Applications list were before rebooting and how to place them back in those exact locations when they automatically launch after reboot.

So, Firefox instance 1 was positioned on monitor 1 of 3 and in workspace 1 before reboot.  Firefox instance 2 was positioned on monitor 3 of 3 and in workspace 3 before reboot.  I would like each instance to be restored to their previous locations when I reboot the computer that has Ubuntu 22.04.02 installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. What desktop environment are you using? How do you launch the browsers? Why would you expect something to reopen after restart? How have you set that up? You mention autostart in the title, but then not in the question. Is that relevant? How?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.